# New bash on windows 10 cannot use gulp

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed it yesterday, and I cannot find a way to bypass all the errors I get:

- [nodemon] Internal watch failed: watch /home/user/myFolder/whatever EPERM
- listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80

These works on a real linux and surprisingly enough in the cmd shell of windows.
I use NodeJS, npm, bower and gulp.

Comment: you could try cygwin and you may be able to tag it with whatever teh names of those programs are , bower and gulp, and ask on stackoverflow though it may need an improvement to look more like a programmer's question for you to do that.

Comment: Bash for Windows is a beta product. It is a known issue that watch services don't run properly and any node module that requires interaction with the network interface wont work https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13383789-enable-network-interface-enumeraration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [lack of inotify support](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/216) in Windows Subsystem for Linux.  It has been resolved in Windows insider builds and is expected to be generally available in the next Windows release.

Comment: Thank you for the information.
I really look forward to it.